# pandasql: count occurrences of pairs

Tags: sql, sqldf, pandasql

I was trying to count the number of matches that A and B have ever played,
the dataset looks like this:

[image: This is how the data looks like in Notebook]

so the number of matches team1 and team 29 have played is 2 as they each once were HomeTeam and AwayTeam, however, using my query I could only count it as one:

```
SELECT HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, Count(*) AS num_matches
FROM games GROUP BY HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID
```

I know where my problem is but don't know how to solve it.

Comment: With that data, can you post your expected output?

Comment: @FrankerZ She said the expected output is 2 for teams 1 and 29.

Comment: Where is Team 29 the Home Team in your sample dataset?

Comment: Yeah sure, so the task is asked to write in sql languages but in python notebook, so it should return 3 columns, the focal team id, the opposing team ids that have play against the focal team, and the number of times that the two teams have played. I hope it makes sense!

Comment: There's nothing in the question about a focal team, and the query you tried doesn't match a specific team ID.

Answer (score 0):

Put the teams in a common order so the grouping isn't sensitive to whether they're home or away.

```
SELECT GREATEST(HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID) AS team1, LEAST(HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID) AS team2, COUNT(*) as num_matches
FROM games
GROUP BY team1, team2
```